# How to add the OAuth 2.0 bearer token to WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webclient

This is the error response I get when using `WebClient` currently

```
{
  "type": "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title": "Internal Server Error",
  "status": 500,
  "detail": "401 Unauthorized from GET http://localhost:8080/services/user/api/users/1",
  "path": "/api/posts",
  "message": "error.http.500"
}
```

This is how I am using `WebClient`

```
webclient.get().uri(ur).retrieve().bodyToMono(User.class).block();
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a servlet based application since you are subscribing to the `Mono` and blocking.

The first step is to configure `WebClient` with OAuth 2.0 Client support:

```java
@Bean
WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
    ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
            new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    return WebClient.builder()
            .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
            .build();
}
```

Then you can set an `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` as a request attribute:

```java
String body = this.webClient
        .get()
        .attributes(clientRegistrationId("client-id"))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .block();
```

You can find more details in the [Spring Security reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2Client-webclient-servlet).

You can find a full example in the [Spring Security samples GitHub repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/webclient).